# Cannot find 'WeatherManager' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to swift and this is my first question here.

[I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlB00.jpg)

I tried creating a new file in the models and renaming it but that didn't work. It shows the same error.
I tried clearing the build folder(shift+ command + k) and restarting my mac.
I have gone through a few answers here but none of them worked. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Look closely at your Project Navigator. `Model` is red. Check the path in the File Inspector (⌥⌘1). Click on the tiny folder icon below Location and select the actual location.

Comment: It is showing - "Clima/Model/WeatherManager.swift" which i think is the correct location. But i may be wrong.

Comment: Click on the folder icon? Does it show the correct location?

Comment: Yes. It is showing Model at the top. Also the target membership is also showing the appname Clima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new Model folder and moving the file(WeatherManager.swift) solved the issue. But I didn't get why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the solution that worked for me is as follows.
Click on the particular file that's not being found in context, in this case WeatherManager.swift, inspect the file, then check the target membership button, Also do the same for the controller file from which you want to use the WeatherManager, in this case, WeatherViewController.
I hope the attached screenshot helps.

[image]